# Dynamically creating links in TextViews

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview

I need to be able to create a link for a TextView in an app, but the actual URL to which the link will point needs to be added dynamically.

Through research here on SO, I found the following code:

```
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(
                    "<b>text3:</b>  Text with a " +
                    "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">link</a> " +
                    "created in the Java source code using HTML."));
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

This allegedly will set a link in the TextView as it would in HTML.  This is exactly what I need to do, but I need the URL to be dynamic, based on a string variable that would be passed to the `setText()`.  How do I easily go about doing this?

To clarify:  I want to display the word "website" is a link, and I need the URL to which that link directs to be dynamically updated based on the specific path that brought the user to that view.

Thanks!

EDIT:  Here is the updated code:

```
String linkedText = "<b>text3:</b>  Text with a " +
            String.format("<a href=\"%s\">link</a> ", WEB) +
            "created in the Java source code using HTML.";
web.setText(Html.fromHtml(linkedText));

web.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Here is the TextView's XML:

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vWeb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/vPhone"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/webIcon"
            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:textIsSelectable="true" />
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you could try using String.format():

```
String dynamicUrl = "http://www.google.com"; // or whatever you want, it's dynamic

String linkedText = "<b>text3:</b>  Text with a " +
        String.format("<a href=\"%s\">link</a> ", dynamicUrl) +
        "created in the Java source code using HTML.";

textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(linkedText));
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

**Edit:** You also need to remove `android:autoLink="web"` from the XML for this to work.

Comment: this just adds the word "link" to the textview but does not make it clickable.

Comment: I didn't realize that was part of your problem. I ran the code above after copying it into one of my own projects, and it seems to work fine. Is there any non-visible view above the TextView that may be intercepting clicks?

Comment: No, I don't believe so.  The link does not even appear when this is implemented.

Comment: Hmm, that is strange. Could you include the code you're attempting to run (based on my example) as well as the XML for the TextView?

Comment: Edited answer with a fix for you

Answer (score 0):

use property

**android:autoLink="all"**

in textview under your XML file

which handle for all web,email,phone,map so u need to worry about it